# docker build file copying files with square brackets

Tags: docker, next.js

I've been using a docker build file to build my nextjs node application fine for a long while, but today I added nextjs dynamic pages. These pages are named with square brackets e.g. [page].js

If i remove this file my docker file builds fine, so it's definitely to do with the square brackets, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Here's my Docker file:

```
FROM node:10.13-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json ./
USER node
RUN npm install
COPY --chown=node:node . .
EXPOSE 3000
RUN npm run build
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and here's the error

`Error: Could not find a valid build in the '/home/node/app/.next' directory!`

And as I say, it's started since i've added the square brackets in the filename. Unfortunately these files must be named with square brackets to function correctly

Answer (score 1):

According to the [COPY documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy),

> When copying files or directories that contain special characters
>   (such as [ and ]), you need to escape those paths following the Golang
>   rules to prevent them from being treated as a matching pattern. For
>   example, to add a file named arr[0].txt, use the following;

```
ADD arr[[]0].txt /mydir/
```

The only solution that I've been able to find is to copy files with special symbols one by one escaping special characters.

Comment: thanks, this worked! i've added an ADD for each of the files that contain square brackets. I wonder if there's a way to do it for all of them within a directory with . or * or something silimar